# A Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak. Allocated from: in Unity fix

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, crash

I implemented adMob mediation in Unity which has inMobi and Unity ads integrated in it. However my game can be built for android but it is crashing as soon as it starts (after the Unity splash screen is displayed). I suspect that it might be because of warning of the memory leak which is happening(the full stuff indicated below).It is pointing to a code which I never wrote and I had earlier figured out a way to enable full stacktrace as well.

"A Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak. Allocated from:
Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1:.ctor(Byte[], Allocator)".

I tried to fix this but all I got to know you have to do some web request to a using construction as per this discussion https://answers.unity.com/questions/1830563/need-help-on-a-native-collection-has-not-been-disp.html. But I don't clearly understand where this webrequest lies and what exactly to do.

WARNING:

```
A Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak. Allocated from:
Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1:.ctor(Byte[], Allocator)
UnityEngine.Networking.UploadHandlerRaw:.ctor(Byte[])
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest:SetupPost(UnityWebRequest, WWWForm)
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest:Post(String, WWWForm)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[], Exception&)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
Google.PortableWebRequest:StartRequest(HttpMethod, String, IDictionary`2, WWWForm) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/PortableWebRequest.cs:481)
Google.<StartRequestOnMainThread>c__AnonStorey6:<>m__C() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/PortableWebRequest.cs:443)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:486)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__12() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:536)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested(Boolean) (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/chkuang/Workspace/Git/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

I had earlier enabled multidex and I don't understand whats wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like you can search your codebase for instances of UnityWebRequest, and check each one to see whether it's properly wrapped inside a `using` block or otherwise disposed of safely. That should help you find the web request that isn't handled safely and is causing the leak. What do you find when you attempt this?

Comment: @DMGregory I tried searching the codebase for instances of UnityWebRequest, but it cannot find it. I changed the options of the search in Microsoft Visual Studio from all open document, to entire project and entire solution. But still it doesn't find any

Comment: If I cant get any help from here, or reddit,unity forum, whom should I approach for this problem?

Comment: You'll tend to get better answers on StackExchange if you create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: the simplest/shortest set of code and project setup instructions we'd need to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project. That widens your pool of potential answers from just the few who have seen and solved this exact error before to anyone willing to take time to test and troubleshoot using those instructions. Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test hypotheses about its cause and try potential fixes to check whether they work.

Comment: Oh Thanks, by the way I had the previous version of the app with me as a back up. I took that and working on that @DMGregory